# (nginx) Any PHP redirect working fine, except for those in ErrorDocument 404

Tags: php, apache, http, redirect, nginx

I'm running a site that's moving from an Apache to an nginx server. On my site, the **404** `ErrorDocument` begins with a check whether the accessed file is a shortened link or not.

If it is a shortened link, I'm redirecting users to the page it resolves. If not, they'll stay on 404.php.

My redirect looks like this:

```
<?php
    header("Location: $location");
?>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't for work for 404.php, but only for any page **except** 404.php (including other ErrorDocuments), so I think that the problem might be in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` or `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myDomain.vhost`.

I've tried uncommenting anything that has to do with `404`, but without any luck.

By calling the ErrorDocument with with `myDomain.de/err/404.php` or `myDomain.de/404`, everything works fine, but once you call `myDomain.de/somethingThatDoesntExistOnTheServer` it will **not** redirect properly.

Why is `ErrorDocument 404` the only page that refuses to redirect properly?

Here's the configuration files.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default:**

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ err/404.php;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::1;
        deny all;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        # With php5-cgi alone:
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myDomain.vhost:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myDomain.de www.myDomain.de;
    root /var/www/myDomain.de/www;

    if ($http_host != "myDomain.de") {
        rewrite ^ http://myDomain.de$request_uri permanent;
    }

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Make sure files with the following extensions do not get loaded by nginx because nginx would display the source code, and these files can contain PASSWORDS!
    location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
        deny all;
    }

    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
        # http://www.tweaktalk.net/60/nginx-remove-php-file-extension-from-url
        try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    error_page 500 /err/500.php;
    error_page 404 /err/404.php;
    error_page 403 /err/403.php;

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
            try_files $uri = 404;
            root /usr/share/;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            root /usr/share/;
        }
    }

    location /phpMyAdmin {
        rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    # Error documents
    location ~ /\d\d\d {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /err/$1.php;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this behavior doesn't only affect 404 pages. This might even be a bug in nginx.
I'm re-opening this as a new question with clearer information and less code.

**Edit:**

Phew, the solution wasn't easy to track down. :)

For everyone having this problem, just add a "`=`" in your configurations where you define your ErrorDocuments as we've just found out over here, in a clearer version of this question:

[Redirect instead of 404 Error page - Status Code not working (Nginx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20932750/really-weird-redirect-behavior-nginx#20932750)